# glDrawElements VAO/VBO crash on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

I am creating a batching class that uses VAOs and VBOs to manage meshes.  However, when attempting to use glDrawElements, I get EXEC_BAD_ACCESS and GL_INVALID_OPERATION when binding back to my VAO.  Here is the code:

```
glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &arrayID);      
glBindVertexArrayOES(arrayID);    // Bind INTO VAO, opening state

// Load shaders and textures and bind them using glUseProgram etc.

glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
glGenBuffers(1, &indexID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexID); 
glBindVertexArrayOES(0);    // Bind AWAY from VAO, saving state

Glfloat data[length];

glBindVertexArrayOES(arrayID);    // Bind INTO VAO, open state

unsigned int glfloatsize = sizeof(GLfloat);
unsigned int stride = kStride * glfloatsize;

// Fill Vertex information
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertCount * glfloatsize * kStride, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertCount * glfloatsize * kStride, data);   

glEnableVertexAttribArray(kPositionLocation);
glVertexAttribPointer(kPositionLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(kNormalLocation);
glVertexAttribPointer(kNormalLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, BUFFER_OFFSET(3));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(kColorLocation);
glVertexAttribPointer(kColorLocation, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, BUFFER_OFFSET(6));

glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(kTextureLocation);
glVertexAttribPointer(kTextureLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, BUFFER_OFFSET(10));

// Fill Index information
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexCount * sizeof(GLushort), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, indexCount * sizeof(GLushort), index);

glBindVertexArrayOES(0);    // Bind AWAY from VAO, saving state

// DO OTHER STUFF

/** RENDER (EXPLODES WITH EXEC_BAD_ACCESS) **/
glBindVertexArrayOES(arrayID);
glDrawElements(renderMode, indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
glBindVertexArrayOES(0);

/** RENDER (WORKS CORRECTLY [index is a scoped array of GLushorts that are uploaded to the VBO above...]) **/
glBindVertexArrayOES(arrayID);
glDrawElements(renderMode, indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, index);
glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```

Any idea why I am receiving EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when attempting to use a GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER VBO?

Comment: I didn't know that calling `glBindVertexArrayOES(0)` would save any state... Are you sure about that ? My understanding was that saving occurs when `glVertexAttribPointer`is called, for the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, and it occurs when `glBufferData` is called, in the case of the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. See this tutorial : http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tutorial%2005.html

Comment: I rewrote a good portion of my rendering pipeline and can't really say what (if any) solution I came to. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that following statements are true?

- all OpenGL function doesn't set error - call glGetError after EACH of glXYZ function and check the result.
- kStride >= 24
- length == vertCount * kStride
- index array has indexCount elements with GLushort type
- all elements of index array has value less than vertCount value
- there are no other glEnableVertexAttribArray calls

Comment: @Martins Mozeiko -- yes, I traced glGetError all the way until the EXEC_BAD_ACCESS, glDrawArrays sets GL_INVALID_OPERATION before sigaborting.  kStride is 12 (3 vert, 3 norm, 4 color, 2 texuv).  The latter parts are true and if they weren't it is unlikely that the pointer substitution would work (the last part of the original post).  Thanks for the sanity check though!